# IE9 compatibility mode

Tags: view, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

I have an issue with a website not working properly in IE10 (some pages using iframes).  In IE10, I can click on the 'Compatibility view' button and everything works fine again.

To avoid users having to do this, I tried to insert the meta tag  in the header of the master page (it's a .NET website), and also in the root web.config (in the system.webserver config block).  I also tried IE=9, IE-8...

Nothing works.  Is the browser not properly interpreting the tag? I know it sees it because when the tag is there, the 'Compatibility view' icon disappears.  What am I missing?

Comment: It would probably be best to try to work out why IE10 is not working, so it can be fixed, rather than changing to an earlier document mode (browser mode can’t be changed globally unless on the compat list. see  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx) . Does IE10 give any errors in the F12 console? Are you using browser sniffing? Try running through the site scanner on http://modern.ie/

Answer (score 2):

Ie 9 – compatibility: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`
If you want ie 8:  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`
if you want both: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8;">`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1,requiresActiveX=true">
```

Reference: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.1.0/doc/extend.md#internet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

```
example:
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GeneralLedgerCodeListingCustomForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="xyz.GeneralLedgerCodeListingCustomForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
%>
```